# Deleting Records from Documentum

Tags: documentum, documentum-dql

I need to delete a number of records from a Documentum database. As these are Documentum objects I can't just go into the backend SQL and remove them so trying DQL.

```
Delete from cbs_speciality where speciality_id = 'zzz'
```

and I get the error

```
Error occured during query execution :[DM_QUERY_E_TABLE_NO_ACCESS]error: "The table, xxx.cbs_speciality, is not registered or you do not have access to it."
```

If I use

```
Delete from cbs_speciality where speciality_id = 'zzz' ENABLE (ROWBASE)
```

I get a syntax error

Since XXX is the account we use around the installation I am pretty sure it has access, but how can I delete these items.

Comment: You made possibly wrong assumption, XXX is installation owner so it can delete items. Just to add more spice did you know that Documentum distincts installation owner and database owner? Just check acl_name and acl_domain properties for that specific object and check persmissions for your user. If he doesn't have delete permission you can add it.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for Documentum objects deletion is little bit different (without `FROM` and with `OBJECT` keywork):

```
DELETE cbs_speciality OBJECT WHERE speciality_id = 'zzz'
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since I wasn't aware that it was documentum object. cgrim's answer is the right one.

Comment: @AhmetRasitBekar that's great but not awesome. It would be awesome if you were upvoted cgrim answer additionally ;)